# Drawing 132 watts of a 5Ah 12v motorcycle battery

Tags: batteries

My scooter is using a 4Ah 12v battery and has 4 LED headlights, 2 for low beam (5.2w), 2 for high beam (5.2w). By default, it’s using a 2.6w LED for each, so total would be 10.4 if I’m using low and high beam.

It’s getting dimmer now so I’m planning to upgrade to a 33w LED each. So that means if I’m running both near and high beam, I’ll be drawing 132w, although mostly it will be running at low beam which is 66w.  Will this be ok?

Comment: You should check that the wires and switches are rated for the increased current. They probably are not.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will probably redo the headlights wiring.

Answer (score 2):

With 132 Watts you will be drawing 11 A. (I=P/V)

Taking a [random](http://www.yuasabatteries.com/pdfs/NP_4_12_DataSheet.pdf) 4 Ah battery as reference:
[image: 4ah discharge rate]

You will be discharging at 11 / 4 = 2.75 C, meaning you'll deplete it in 5 minutes.

You'd have to find the specifications on your dynamo to see if you have enough power to power the lamps, **and** charge the battery.

*Don't wait long at the traffic lights.*

Comment: Now that's worrying. While at the traffic lights, I'll probably just be on the near beam which is 66w (33w*2), I'll be safe?

Comment: @xviiviiixiv I'm saying that you're mounting too much light on your scooter.

Comment: =( the default light and the roads are really bad here